# Rewriting URL on dreamhost

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite a URL for a Dreamhost served website.

I want to do the following:

**Goal**:

> Rewrite only URLs that start with an `x`.

This:

> `http:// domain.com/x23`

Should become:

> ```
> http:// domain.com/index.php/lookup/code/x23
> ```

I tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(x[0-9a-z])$ index.php/lookup/code/$0 [L]
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a quantifier for `[0-9a-z]`. Your expression does only allow one character of `[0-9a-z]`. Try the `+` quantifier for *one or more repetitions*:

```
RewriteRule ^x[0-9a-z]+$ index.php/lookup/code/$0 [L]
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the answer. Somehow to make it work on Dreamhost I also needed to add a question mark after php -> RewriteRule ^(x[0-9a-z]+)$ index.php?/lookup/code/$0 [L]

Any ideas why?

Comment: @mschoening: Maybe *AcceptPathInfo* is not on (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
^(x[0-9a-z]+)$   # Note the +, so it matches more than one
```